how to config advanced filter for STReport lincebi Pentaho
I have this version of STRport Versión: 2.0.7, only with a filter like this (simple version nothing dinamic)

However, I saw in this link
https://youtu.be/O8NS7OBCpX4?t=59
https://todobi.com/nuevas-funcionalidades-de-filtros/
the possibility of using an advanced filter. Does anyone know how to configure it?

I expected configure filters for example for date like current date instead of a static day as parameter
